# How to select single column using ruby activerecord query

Tags: activerecord, ruby-1.9.2

I am having two classes under migration dir.

```
class1
  create_table :table1 do |t|
    t.integer :name
  end
end

class2
  create_table :table2 do |t|
    t.integer :table1_id
    t.integer :name
    t.text :value 
   end
end
```

I want to fetch only value column from table2 using conditions table2.table1_id = "1" and table2.name = "A"

How to write this in ruby?
I want to get the text value as a result.
Same as like sql query

```
select value from table2 where table1_id = 1 and name = 'A';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrive record by applying query like this.

and it give you the whole row as result.You can iterate through this array and can get your 
desired values.

@array = Table2.where("table1_id = ? And name = ?",1,'A')

it will work fine.

Or

@array = Table2.find(:first,:conditions => "[table1_id = '1' And name = 'A']"

but ruby give you warning that this code is deprecate but it works

But the first query is most better.

Hope it will works for u!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Table2.where("table1_id = ? And name = ?",1,'A').select("value")
```